# XMLELEMENT() function not recognize the value of variable as tag name

Tags: oracle11g

I am using XMLELEMENT(tagname,value) in the SELECT query. it is not recognize the variable's values. instead of this, it s taking variable name as tag-name.

//ex

```
l_0_l   := t_array(l_index) || '-ANI-II'; -- runtime value is "A-ANI-II"

SELECT (XMLELEMENT(l_ii, NULL) ||'') 
  INTO l_temp 
  FROM dual;

dbms_output.put_line(l_temp );

expected output :<A-ANI-II/>
acutal output :<L_II/>
```

My Question like : How do I supply the tag-name using the variable at runtime?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks whoever tryied solution for this question.

Finally, I got resolution for my problem.

"evalname()" has resolved my problem. this method is returning the value of that variable to XMLELEMENT().

```
SELECT (XMLELEMENT(evalname(l_ii), NULL) ||'') 
  INTO l_temp 
  FROM dual;

Now, I am getting output like :<A-ANI-II/>
```